# mysqldump not on wamp server

Tags: mysql, database, sql, mysqldump

I am trying to use mysqldump on my wamp server mysql console however, it doesn't seem to have mysqldump included. I found the mysqldump.exe file in this location:

```
/cygdrive/c/wamp/bin/mysql/mysql5.6.12/bin/mysqldump.exe
```

How do I use it in the MySqlConsole?

I was trying to do a mysqldump to copy a database into a new database. When I flagged for help, it turns out the mysql didn't have support for mysqldump but I found the executable in the hopes of getting mysqldump support on mysql which is the link above.

I'm really new to mysql so there might be potential something I really didn't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, set (include) the path of `mysqldump.exe` into the `PATH` environment variable like this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;\Path\to\mysqldump.exe
```

Second, You need NOT to run `mysqldump` command from `mysqlconsole`, it should be run from the normal command prompt, once the `PATH` is set (as mentioned above).

For example, you may use below URL to create and restore mysql backups:

[Backup and Restore MySQL Database Using mysqldump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

Third, the path you mentioned above shows the path from a Linux/Unix machine (having forward slashes). In case you're using mysql in linux, I'd suggest you to use the native (Linux) installation (in place of using layered Cygwin etc.)

Comment: That was it. Also, I was using it on windows hence the cygwin. Thanks for the response.